# How to fix unnecessary double boot options in UEFI?

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi

I have many (almost 15) unnecessary double boot options in my Asus h81m-cs motherboards UEFI menu 
I tried resetting UEFI by shortening pins and removing CMOS battery
But that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than shorting pins, I'd recommend a software solution. There are a number of EFI editing tools around (which I haven't used).

Example 1:
The free version of [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) says it can manage and remove UEFI options: 
[image: EasyUEFI image]

Example 2:
[Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) contains [OS-Uninstaller](https://sourceforge.net/p/os-uninstaller/wiki/Home/), which should allow you to remove unwanted entries. You would need to download the image file and then make a bootable USB, and then set your computer to boot from it, following the guides on the Sourceforge page from then on.
[image: OS uninstall image]

Comment: Thank you. Right now no OS is installed on my PC, actually Linux mint is installed but I cannot use it because mouse is not working at all in Linux mint though mouse works in UEFI. I tried using 'DriveDroid' Android app which lets us boot isos through Android phone. But when I connect my phone with drivedroid enabled the UEFI hangs at the first screen which says press del to enter into UEFI. So I cannot enter into those bootable media. What's the problem here? How to solve this ?

Comment: that sounds like another question. Maybe you cold start a question asking this specifically. Probably has to do with system setup settings.